# Code signing: which timestamp servers are more reliable?

Tags: code-signing

We run some experiments and DigiCert timestamp server was the fasted and most reliable. It was able to timestamp 2500 signatures within 3'48'' with no failures. But just in case it really throttles us or it is not reachable for whatever reason, what are the next fast and reliable timestamp servers?

We would prefer something that is already in the Trusted Root CA list in Windows. That pretty much limits us to Microsoft, GlobalSign, VeriSign, Sectigo and Thawte. But none of these seem to provide the same level of quality of service of DigiCert.

It looks like the Apple timestamping server is also very reliable. Unfortunately it is not in the Windows Trusted Root CA store by default.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We finally decided on these servers:

- http://timestamp.digicert.com
- http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp
- http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode
- http://timestamp.sectigo.com